# How to create a new keyword in tridion core service?

Tags: core-service, sdl-tridion

```
foreach (System.Globalization.CultureInfo ci in System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultures(System.Globalization.CultureTypes.AllCultures))
        {
             KeywordData keyword = (KeywordData)client.GetDefaultData(ItemType.Keyword, category.Id);
           // Tridion.KeywordData keyword = (Tridion.KeywordData)client.GetDefaultData(Tridion.ItemType.Keyword, category.Id);
            keyword.Id = "tcm:0-0-0";
            keyword.Title = ci.TextInfo.CultureName;
            keyword.Key = ci.TextInfo.CultureName;
            //keyword.Title = "Sea-web the ultimate marine online database";
            //keyword.Key = null;
            keyword = (KeywordData)client.Create(keyword, new ReadOptions()) as KeywordData;
            //  client.Create(keyword, null);
        }
```

here am getting error in

```
KeywordData keyword = (KeywordData)client.GetDefaultData(ItemType.Keyword, category.Id);
```

GetDefaultData

Exception: FaultException There are no arguments corresponds to the given parameter "ReadOptions"

I dont Know where am going wrong as am new to core service can some one help with the sample code if possible

Comment: go thorugh this https://tridionwithanupam.wordpress.com/category/tridion-core-service-basics/ help you.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the Core Service CHM document, it appears that the `GetDefaultData` method expects three arguments to be passed in:

```
IdentifiableObjectData GetDefaultData(
ItemType itemType,
string containerId,
ReadOptions readOptions)
```

Therefore, I think that this line:

```
KeywordData keyword = (KeywordData)client.GetDefaultData(ItemType.Keyword, category.Id);
```

Needs to be changed to:

```
KeywordData keyword = (KeywordData)client.GetDefaultData(ItemType.Keyword, category.Id, new ReadOptions());
```